# How to run an interval on component init only once with angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, setinterval

I have an interval launched in my component:

```
export class FoobarComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.startInterval();
    }

    startInterval() void {
        setInterval(() => { console.log('Hi'); }, 1000);
    }    
}
```

Each time the component is called, a new interval is created in addition to the previous ones.

I tried to used an ID (as I used to do with plain JS before) with something like:

```
export class FoobarComponent implements OnInit {

    intervalId: Number;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.startInterval();
    }

    startInterval() void {
        if(this.intervalId) { // always undefined 
            window.clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        }
        this.intervalId = window.setInterval(() => { console.log('Hi'); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

But it's not working since `intervalId` became undefined each time the component is called. So the previous intervals keep running while a new one is created.

I don't know how to stop an interval already running. 
Could you help me to do it?

Comment: make intervalID static, that way you'll be able to access in all components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the **intervalID** static. That way all class instances will be able to access the same one.

```js
export class FoobarComponent implements OnInit {

    static intervalId: Number;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.startInterval();
    }

    startInterval() void {
        if(FoobarComponent.intervalId) { // always undefined 
            window.clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        }
        FoobarComponent.intervalId = window.setInterval(() => { console.log('Hi'); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, please mark the answer as the correct one as well for future readers to know that's the way to go. :)